# Migrate existing database to mirrored database on Azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, database-mirroring

I have setup 3 Sql VM's on Azure for database mirroring as described in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870961.aspx) with the idea being that we move our current database, which is currently on a single VM outside of Azure. Everything works so far, except now I am stumped at how I move my current database over to the new environment? I initially tried to restore our current database to both the primary and mirror server and then enable mirroring, but got an error

> Database "xxxxxx" is not configured for database mirroring

on the primary database. What are the steps involved in moving an existing database over to this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get that error if you try to run the `alter database [yourdb] set partner...` statement at the primary first. You need to run that alter statement at the secondary and then run it at the primary. So, in the link that you pointed to, it seems that the last thing in step 10 hasn't been run yet.